# Design pattern for implementing LastUpdated and UpdatedBy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have been pondering this problem for a while now and cannot think of an acceptable solution. I have an application that is planned to become very large. Because of this I am trying to make it modular. It is based on MVC4. I have not decided on using a ORM or mapping everything myself. I would like to have the following structure:

```
----------------------
| Database
----------------------
| Data/Data Access Layer (Class Library) (Objects reside here)
----------------------
| Core MVC Project (User and Session are stored here)
----------------------
| MVC Modules
```

I want to keep the validation of the `UpdatedBy` field as close to the database as possible, possibly in the Data/Data Access layer. The problem is I want to store the `user` in the `Session` and do the validation in the class library (where there is no `Session`). I also want to avoid as much as possible passing the `user` all over the place. Is there a way to store the user in the `Session` and have the Data Access layer access that info without being passed the `user`? Anybody have any recommendations on how to do this elegantly?

**EDIT:** I want to keep `validation`, and `CRUD` activities as close to the Data layer as possible where the Core MVC project just calls `Save()` on an object and the Data layer validates the object, figures out what user modified or created it and saves it to the DB.

**EDIT 2:** It is imperative that the Data layer have absolutely no dependencies in the MVC layer.

Comment: A dependency can be created and injected into the Data Access layer that fetches the information from the session when it is created but shields the data access layer from having a dependency on the session object.

Comment: @Grax how would I go about that? I have little knowledge in dependency injection.

Comment: What techniques do you keep your layers separate now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LastUpdated` can easily be implemented with a `Trigger` on DB Insert/Updates, but the `UpdatedBy` is a bit trickier.

A key question is "does your business layer require knowledge of who is using it?"  If so, then the interfaces can be designed to require that a Username is provided when making actions.  If not then you need to make the data accessible from within/behind the business layer, but without being explicitly provided to it (such as with Dependency Injection, or by providing a Context that is availalble throughout).

You could consider creating a seperate audit-trail using ActionFilters around your controller actions, which provides easy access to the `Session`, and can create a running history of actions your users take.  This may or may not correctly 100% to your database records, but does provide a clear history of the actions of the application--which is valuable in its own right.

You could also consider using a `Command` pattern, whereby the application generates specific commands (e.g. an `UpdateWidgetName` command) that are enacted on the business/data layer.  In some regards this is how MVC already works, but having an explicit `Command` which captures the user and date is still a useful addition to your business layer.

---

Also be aware of the shortcomings of keeping this on the record itself.  You'll only know who last edited the record--you won't be able to tell specifically what they edited, or who edited it previously.  For relatively simple scenarios this is usually sufficient, but it is far from providing actual historical data for the record.

If you really want 100% auditing you should look at the `Event Sourcing` design pattern, where effectively if an action isn't audited then it didn't happen.  It's a very different paradigm from the typical CRUD approach, but is very powerful (albeit more complicated to design initially)

---

One other note: consider seperating your business and persistence code into two layers.  Tying them together makes the business logic tightly coupled to persistence (bad), which will prevent it from being reused.  Look into implementing a `Repository` which is dedicated to persisting and retrieving your business objects.  It pays off.

Comment: Sorry I am self-taught and a little rusty on formal name. Would the business layer be the Data/Data Access Layer? What I am really trying to do is save a history of who changed what and when to the database. I believe that is what you are talking about with ActionFilter, am I correct?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_layer#Business_logic_layer <-- there's a good intro.  A well designed business layer should be reusable, and shouldn't have any non-business dependencies (a business layer that has to have SQL, or is only usable by MVC, would be considered poorly designed).  Create a dedicated Project for your business layer, and try to avoid adding assembly references as much as possible

Comment: I'm self-taught, too.  Learning the SOLID principles (and how to apply them) was a huge milestone, other good resources are patterns books (PofEAA, head first design patterns, etc) and a personal eye-opener was "Clean Code".  I've recommended them to a lot of interns and generally they agree they're a big help in getting oriented

Comment: @STW "a business layer that has to have SQL"  I've found most application only ever have one data store at a time, so when it comes time to change the data access strategy the existing code is ripped out and new data access code added.  If your business layer doesn't let the data layer leak to the UI at all, this really isn't an issue.

Comment: @Andy - that's called a "self-fulfilling prophecy".  Not to mention coupling the two together makes testing more difficult.  Invest a little in a clean architecture up front and you'll realize the savings.

Comment: @STW You can properly decouple things within a library and still make use of things like SqlConnection for the implementation.  The business library would then "depend" on Sql while allowing for testing and potential changes in the future.  If you're talking about making things decoupled enough so that you could even support things like document storage with no changes to the BL, I'll just call that YAGNI until there's a hard requirement to do actually support it.  The trick with design is to find the balance between unmaintanable code and over-engineering.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a structure like this in your application, you can define some core interfaces that can be used throughout your application (like `ICurrentUserProvider`), and then you can implement those interfaces in the parts of your application where they are best implemented, without creating a tight coupling or dependency to that specific part of the application.

[image: Project Structure]

When your web project is initialized, it can initialize your DI framework so that your controllers get their dependencies injected into them. That way your controller gets the Business Layer services it needs, and those Business Layer services have the data-layer implementations they need (without actually having a direct dependency on them), and the data access object gets the service that can tell it who the current user is (without depending directly on the MVC layer).